# Not sure if addRating and getAverage methods are correct

Tags: java

Design a class Movie that contains information about a movie. The class has the following attributes (member variables):

- The movie name
- The MPAA rating (for example, G, PG, PG-13, R)
- The number of people that have rated this movie as a 1 (Terrible)
- The number of people that have rated this movie as a 2 (Bad)
- The number of people that have rated this movie as a 3 (OK)
- The number of people that have rated this movie as a 4 (Good)
- The number of people that have rated this movie as a 5 (Great)

The class should have the following member functions:

- A constructor that allows the programmer to create the object with a specified name and MPAA rating. The number of people rating the movie should be set to 0 in this constructor.
- Accessor and mutator functions for the movie name and MPAA rating
- A function addRating that takes an integer as an input parameter. The function should verify that the parameter is a number between 1 and 5, and if so, increment the number of people rating the movie that match the input parameter. For example, if 3 is the input parameter, then the number of people that rated the movie as a 3 should be incremented by 1.
- A function getAverage that returns the average value for all of the movie ratings

When I run the program it does not show the correct average, for example if I rated ice-age a 3 and 4, its average should be 3.5, but instead it gives my the last rating, which is a 4. Here are my two methods:

```
public static void addRating(int rating)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    movieRating = rating;

    numberOfPeopleRated = 0;
    switch(movieRating)
    {
        case 1:
            numberOfPeopleRated++;
            break;
        case 2:
            numberOfPeopleRated++;
            break;
        case 3:
            numberOfPeopleRated++;
            break;
        case 4:
            numberOfPeopleRated++;
            break;
        case 5:
            numberOfPeopleRated++;
            break;
    }

    System.out.println("You rated " + movieName + " a " + movieRating);
}

public static void getAverage()
{
    totalMovieRating += movieRating;
    double averageRating = totalMovieRating / numberOfPeopleRated;
    System.out.println("The average Rating is " + averageRating);
}
```

Comment: Are `totalMovieRating` and `numberOfPeopleRated` integers or doubles?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We don't know your definition of `totalMovieRating` and `numberOfPeopleRated`.

Comment: Currently, your `switch` statement can be replaced by `numberOfPeopleRated = (movieRating >= 1 && movieRating <= 5) ? 1 : 0;`. And what is `keyboard` used for?

Comment: Better swap `totalMovieRating += movieRating;` to method `addRating`. Hence right now you just add it, when you calc Average (but then maybe several times...)

Comment: I think you need to reconsider what "average" means. You need to add up all of the stars, then divide by the total number of ratings. You're not doing that.

Comment: totalMovieRating and numberOfPeopleRated are both integers. totalMovieRating gets the total ratings when a user enters a rating. numberOfPeopleRated gets the amount of rating a person rated. for example if two people rated movie1 a 4, numberOfPeopleRated will be 2 and totalMovieRating will be 8.

Comment: Then you have to cast `double` to your calculation: `(double) totalMovieRating / numberOfPeopleRated;` since else you will get an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've got some semantical (logical) mistakes in there.

1. `numberOfPeopleRated` gets set to 0 every time.
2. the switch is redundant
3. you add the `movieRating` to `totalMovieRating` at the wrong place!
4. you have to be careful when you're calculating the average (double-integer conversion problems)

The corrected version would look somewhat like this:

```
public static void addRating(int rating) {
    if (rating >= 1 && rating <= 5) {
        numberOfPeopleRated++;
        totalMovieRating += rating;
        System.out.println("You rated " + movieName + " a " + rating);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Wrong rating");
    }
}

public static void getAverage() {
    double averageRating = ((double)totalMovieRating) / numberOfPeopleRated;
    System.out.println("The average Rating is " + averageRating);
}
```

Comment: Also, variable `movieRating` is no longer defined (or is not updated); also, the scanner is never used. Otherwise fine.

Comment: @tobias_k oh you're right! I'll correct that. Damn you copy&paste ;)

Comment: Thank You, now I understand. I corrected my program and now it works fine